# CakePhp upgrade from 1.3 to 2.0.1 using Shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Can someone tell me the exact steps to follow on how to do this. the documentation on the cakephp site isnt very helpfull.

I have a clean vanilla copy of cake 2.0.1 on d:\cake201. 
I have added the console path in this dir to my PATH var

the project is in `d:\www\sbm\trunk\`

when navigate to `d:\www\sbm\trunk\` in command prompt and run `cake upgrade all`  it modifies the `d:\www\sbm\trunk\cake` folder and files in there have syntax errors.

when i navigate to `d:\www\sbm\trunk\app` and run `cake upgrade all` it looks for the `d:\www\sbm\trunk\cake\bootstrap.php` but in v2 the cake folder is in `d:\www\sbm\trunk\lib\cake`

please help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to have a copy of your App Folder into the D:\cake201 folder. Now navigate to d:\cake201\app and run cake upgrade all

This should do everything for you ! :)

NOTE: Try not to take the config folder with u and edit that manually, this will be much more easier

Comment: If you got the basics, this might also help you to upgrade some more things: https://github.com/dereuromark/upgrade